# Delete instance the RAM did not recycling?

Tags: openstack

From the Admin -> SYSTEM -> Instances , we can see I only have two VMs now. ( Before I deleted serval instances, now only leave two, all of the two instances are in the ha-node2, the compute-node2 and controller-node2 are on the ha-node2). Every instance takes 512MB RAM.

[image: image description]

But in the Admin -> SYSTEM -> Hypervisors, there takes away (512MB + 1.5GB)  RAM.

[image: image description]
<sub>(source: [openstack.org](https://ask.openstack.org/upfiles/1502103889363712.png))</sub>

Where is the reason, why there takes away those ram?  is when I delete the instance did not recycling the ram?
And why the  pie chart of Memory used are 7.8GB of 15.3GB, however there takes 2GB away from the 15.3GB (7.6GB + 7.6GB).

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue where the quota data isn't updated to reflect the correct usage amount. The vCPU usage is also 0, when you are using at least 2.

The issue is related to:

https://specs.openstack.org/openstack/nova-specs/specs/mitaka/approved/refresh-quotas-usage.html

I would suggest checking out the blueprint + bug fix and see if the CLI option works for you.

There is also a workaround to update MySQL manually and change a value to -1 or 0 (depending on the version you are using). This update will be made in the Nova database.

> > update quota_usages set in_use='0' where project_id='YOUR_PROJECT_ID';